# Http.request results in TypeError: "values is null"

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-httpclient

I am trying to execute saved requests from the localstorage.

When executing `http.request()` it returns te following error:
[image: Error when subscribing on http.request()]

This is te code responsible for the sending the requests:

```js
public sync() {
    this.setSyncState(SyncState.Syncing)
    Array.from(this.stateManager.entries()).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let newRequest: HttpRequest<any> = { ...value }

      this.http.request(
        newRequest.method,
        newRequest.urlWithParams,
        { 
          body: newRequest.body, 
          headers: newRequest.headers, 
          params: newRequest.params,
          reportProgress: newRequest.reportProgress, 
          responseType: newRequest.responseType,
          withCredentials: newRequest.withCredentials
        }
      ).subscribe(
        event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.stateManager.delete(key)
            console.log("Request from cache succeeded")
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Request from cache failed", error)
        }
      )
    })
    if (Array.from(this.stateManager.entries()).length < 0) {
      this.setSyncState(SyncState.Synced)
    } else {
      this.setSyncState(SyncState.SyncFailed)
    }
  }
```

The stateManager.entries() returns the saved requests in de localstorage, as a Map.

Can anyone point me in some direction to look? I can't seem to find the origin of the error.

Comment: any update on this

Comment: It had to do with the way I saved the requests in the localstorage. I used JSON Stringify to save the bulk data in the localstorage. When retrieving it from localstorage I parsed it to JSON. Turns out that either stringify or parse only works until a max depth. So the data was not fully converted and hence broken, what explains the error a bit.

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually my problem is, I have a node js API backend (which is working fine, tested with Postman) frontend is angular, I'm trying to fetch the profile information of the users from the node js API, when I'm executing the service to contact API I get 'values is null'  error I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If you can hep me that would me more help full bcos last three days facing this issue. please do the needfull.

Comment: I think you are better off with creating a new SO question for that, as I don't have NodeJS experience and have no visual of your code. Add the Angular and NodeJS code in the question and provide the link to the question here!